# Is there always motion, when force is present? Is all motion vibration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, vibrations

Even when you are seated in a chair, the chair is pushing up on you and you down on the chair (manifesting in the form of ~650N).

While there is no obvious observable motion, is it not possible that these forces are the results of a continuous series of (nearly) sub-detectible micro-vibrations?

So then, are these vibrations, or whatever this micro-motion may be presenting itself as, what allows this kind of force to maintain itself? Is there any reason to believe that this might be the case?

Also, is all motion vibration?

Comment: thank you for the response. 

so pretty much the entire force resulting from gravity -> me -> chair <- me, is a result of electrical repulsion, and not any real physical contact? 

what are other types of motion then? for instance, as you continue to break down a sequence of motion into smaller and smaller units, until it nearly reaches a "moment", why would this motion not start to look more and more like vibration?

Comment: I agree, no "real" physical contact. I do not know how to interpret linear or rotational motion in terms of vibrational motion, in a way that is simpler than those motions themselves. But perhaps you could. Let me know.

Comment: The way I see it is, even for something like linear motion, at any individual moment, there will be no movement. So, there must be some kind of 'jump' taking place between each moment, which is what allows distance to be traversed. as a collection of these 'jumps' begins to compile, it starts to take on the appearance of vibration (as a lot of consecutive jumps) and then eventually fluid motion (as approaching infinite number of consecutive jumps). Don't know if any of that means anything, just an idea I had.

Comment: @fernandopessoa - This is not the site for espousing an "idea you just had".

Comment: @DavidHammen What's the site for that then? I thought the point of this site was to acquire a deeper understanding of physics? Or is it only a place to get other people to do your math homework? 

I don't see any problem with going into further discussion of a topic in the comments section. Maybe I should have posted this in the philosophy section - I bet they aren't so close minded there.

Comment: @fernandopessoa wrote:  *"I thought the point of this site was to acquire a deeper understanding of physics?"*  Why do you think that?

Comment: This is a good site for acquiring a deeper knowledge of physics -- if you use it right. Asking about an "idea I just had" is not using it right.

Comment: @DavidHammen I simply had a question and posted it because I did not know the answer myself. What if it wasn't "an idea I just had"? What if was an idea that has been plaguing me for weeks, months, that I could not manage to solve? I don't think I should be berated just because my question wasn't in the form of an equation, or because it may be a bit more open ended. Why not take just thirty seconds of your time and disprove my idea, if it is so obviously a waste of space on stackexchange... At least then the thread will die.

Comment: @fernandopessoa I understand you are pissed off, but your reaction is too emotional, almost childish. The only way people in this forum will take you seriously is if you put some effort. If you had an idea that bothered you for years, why didn't you try to study and understand physics first? For today's standards, a vague idea is useless unless it can be expressed mathematically and results in predictions, regardless of how much time your mind has spent thinking about it

Comment: While I acknowledge that my remark was a bit derogatory perhaps, and was obviously an exaggeration, my question was real, and what I said was not without a grain of truth. I was just looking to flesh out an idea. Just because someone may not find the discussion worthy of their time, doesn't mean that the idea deserves to be smothered. my idea was vague, but that was exactly why i posted it - because i was unable to clarify it myself. in any case, it is nice to see the omnipresent elitist attitude on physics.stackexchange. I no longer care to continue a discussion here. thanks for your answer

Comment: You have to accept that there are minds that work at higher levels than yours (and mine)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that in the real world, there is always thermal noise, so the atoms on the chair "micro vibrate", however this will only contribute, at the best, for you to micro vibrate too. The actual force that keeps you on the seat is the electrical force (repulsive) between the electrons in your butt (or in your pants if you are not naked) and those in the chair. This force exists regardless of the noise-added thermal vibrations. 
And no, not all motion is vibration.